# iOS Application Loader ERROR ITMS-4238 - Cordova - Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

Using Visual Studio 15 with Cordova plugin we submitted our iOS app version 1.0.0 (major.minor.build) and discovered an issue. We rejected the app in iTunes connect and increased the build number to 1 to get around error ITMS-4238 in application loader suggesting that the same app with the same version number is already submitted for review, which is correct. The remedy would be to change the major, minor, or build number for the new build. However, after changing the build number in config.xml the app builder still shows the ipa built for version 1.0.0. In fact changing the major/minor/build seems to have no impact on what the app builder sees as the version number for the built package as it continues to show 1.0.0.

Any suggestions as to what step we are missing would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK - Here's the answer to the riddle. The build process from Visual Studio creates a brand new ipa file on the Mac and does not replace the existing ipa. The application builder automatically points to the existing build, which you would be trying to replace in the app store. So in order to pick the new build you have to do a search when browsing for the package using the application builder, sort by date, and pick the latest ipa file.